# Restrict SSH login to local network: VPN connection not allowed

Tags: ssh, sshd, openssh

There are two (unix) users who are allowed to connect to my Debian Wheezy server using ssh: *git* and *peter*. While git is allowed to connect from everywhere, peter (who is in the sudo group) should be only allowed to connect from my local network.

I therefore added the line

> AllowUsers git peter@192.168.2.0/24

to my */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

And it first seemed to work, as git is allowed to connect remotely over the internet, while peter isn't.

My desktop, which has the ip address 192.168.2.24 is allowed to connect as *peter*, but my laptop isn't when connected using VPN (with local ip 192.168.2.201). It works when using it directly connected to my LAN.

This is what I can find in the */var/log/auth.log* file. It doesn't make any sense to me, why is that IP not allowed?

> Feb  2 11:44:54 srv sshd[7275]: User peter from 192.168.2.201 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
>
> Feb  2 11:44:54 srv sshd[7275]: input_userauth_request: invalid user peter [preauth]

Comment: What does "with local ip 192.168.2.201" mean? What is the output of `ip addr` on the laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
AllowUsers git peter@192.168.2.*
```

or for example:

```
AllowUsers git peter@192.168.2.2??
```

if only 200-254 are allocated for VPN connections.

And make sure to read `man ssh_config` (the section PATTERNS). Yes, that's `ssh_config`, not `sshd_config`. But if you read the latter, you'll notice it refers to the former.